# Ubuntu 22.04 and switch between minimized windows

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-tweaks

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and the GNOME Tweaks. The issue is that I cannot seem to find the `Switch between minimized windows` option anymore. When I press `Activities` I would like not to see the minimized windows. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any version of gnome Shell, hidden windows always have been shown in the overview. You can change that behavior with the Gnome Shell extension [Hide minimized](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2639/hide-minimized/) by danigm.